# PHP Arithmetic Operators are not working in wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why but when I use this shortcode to get child date of birth by using Arithmetic Operators is not work.
Did anyone know why it's not working or what I am doing wrong ?

```
 function get_chid_age_code() {
    $get_date = vp_metabox('wcbox_widget_id.group.0.date_widget');
    $get_month = vp_metabox('wcbox_widget_id.group.0.month_widget');    
    $get_year = vp_metabox('wcbox_widget_id.group.0.year_widget');
    $x = the_time('Y'); // 2016
    $y =  $get_year ; // 2000
    echo $x - $y;
    }
add_shortcode( 'get_chid_age', 'get_chid_age_code' );
```

this code should echo out "16" but I am getting is the value "20162000"

Comment: Try with `intval`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: Or try setting the $x and $y with a cast like so: $x = (int) the_time('Y');

Comment: Check the data type for both $x and $y. If both are not int, type cast them.
 PHP you can type cast to int easily using(int) in front of variable